# Unable to remove Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (ENU)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a problem with SQL Server Management Studio. When I  open it I get this error: "`Invalid license data.Reinstall is required.`"

This is because Visual Studio 2010 Shell needs to be reinstalled, but when I try to remove it I get this error:

```
[04/11/17,20:28:57] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU: [2] ERROR:Error 1305.Error reading from file C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\VsDebugPresentationPackage\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\VsDebugPresentationPackage.dll.  Verify that the file exists and that you can access it.
```

I changed file permissions, but nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10